# Fit bounds with padding deck.gl mapbox

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, react-map-gl, deck.gl

I'm trying to use fiBounds with the WebMercatorViewport object but getting an error about the padding property.

my code:

```
const initialViewState: IViewport | WebMercatorViewport = useMemo(() => {
if (locationsFitBounds) {
  const minLat: number = Math.min(...locationsFitBounds.map((l: MapLocation) => l.latitude))
  const maxLat: number = Math.max(...locationsFitBounds.map((l: MapLocation) => l.latitude))
  const minLng: number = Math.min(...locationsFitBounds.map((l: MapLocation) => l.longitude))
  const maxLng: number = Math.max(...locationsFitBounds.map((l: MapLocation) => l.longitude))
  const southWest: [number, number] = [minLng, minLat]
  const northEast: [number, number] = [maxLng, maxLat]
    return new WebMercatorViewport({ width: 1920, height: 400 }).fitBounds([southWest, northEast], {padding: 200})
} else {
  return viewport
}
}, [locationsFitBounds, viewport])

 <React.Fragment>
  <DeckGL
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    controller={true}
    initialViewState={initialViewState}
  >
    <Map
      attributionControl={false}
      style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
    />
  </DeckGL>
</React.Fragment>
```

The inital render is working well but when the state is changing (closing the map, updating states) I'm getting the error:

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'padding' of object '#<WebMercatorViewport>'
    at positionChildrenUnderViews (position-children-under-views.ts:60:1)
    at deckgl.ts:254:1
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16175:1)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:20023:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22465:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4161:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4210:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4274:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27405:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26513:1)
```

I'm using:
deck.gl: "8.8.20"
react-map-gl": "7.0.20"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution from [git discussion](https://github.com/visgl/deck.gl/discussions/7526)
The useMemo should return a simple viewport and not a WebMercatorViewport object:

```
  const initialViewState: IViewport = useMemo(() => {
    if (fitLocations) {
      const minLat: number = Math.min(...fitLocations.map((l: MapLocation) => l.latitude))
      const maxLat: number = Math.max(...fitLocations.map((l: MapLocation) => l.latitude))
      const minLng: number = Math.min(...fitLocations.map((l: MapLocation) => l.longitude))
      const maxLng: number = Math.max(...fitLocations.map((l: MapLocation) => l.longitude))
      const southWest: [number, number] = [minLng, minLat]
      const northEast: [number, number] = [maxLng, maxLat]
      const { latitude, longitude, zoom } = new WebMercatorViewport({ width: 800, height: 600 }).fitBounds(
        [southWest, northEast],
        { padding: 100 }
      )
      return { ...viewport, latitude, longitude, zoom }
    } else {
      return viewport
    }
  }, [fitLocations, viewport])
```

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox offers the bounds as part of the initial state.

See `options.bounds` on the [Mapbox API](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map)

> The initial bounds of the map. If bounds is specified, it overrides
> center and zoom constructor options.

I am not using `deck.gl`, but here is what did with `react-map-gl`.

```
<Map
  initialViewState={{
    bounds: getBoundingBox(fitLocations),
    fitBoundsOptions: { padding: 60 },
  }}
  >
  ...
  </Map>
```

For generating the bounding box we can use the same [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74913636/7883067) provided by on [Ar26](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9596473/ar26).

```
const getBoundingBox = (fitLocations) => {
      const minLat: number = Math.min(...fitLocations.map((l: MapLocation) => l.latitude))
      const maxLat: number = Math.max(...fitLocations.map((l: MapLocation) => l.latitude))
      const minLng: number = Math.min(...fitLocations.map((l: MapLocation) => l.longitude))
      const maxLng: number = Math.max(...fitLocations.map((l: MapLocation) => l.longitude))
      const southWest: [number, number] = [minLng, minLat]
      const northEast: [number, number] = [maxLng, maxLat]
      return [southWest, northEast]

}
```